# Sync passwords from 2 different iCloud accounts (2 Keychains)

Tags: macos, icloud, keychain

How can I copy all of my keychain passwords to another keychain? I have two  different Mac computers with two different iCloud accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can export your Keychain item(s) to a file from one computer and then import that file into the Keychain to your second computer using [Keychain Access](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac).  Apple has step-by-step instructions on its Support site:

[Import and export keychain items using Keychain Access on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/import-and-export-keychain-items-kyca35961/mac)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to copy them manually.

Comment: maybe a way to script this ? I am not going to copy +1000 passwords manually